# Blank space left after trying to hide Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I've 3 fragments and I'm trying to hide toolbar from one of the fragments using `((AppCompactActivity)getActivity()).getSuppotActionBar().hide`

It is simply hiding the contents of the  contents of the toolbar and still there is a blank space left as shown in the image below

[image: ref Image]

I've read a same post on this issue but none of the ans givin there have solved my problem.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: please share you xml code

Answer (score 0):

**Write this in the fragment you wish to specifically hide the toolbar**

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
}
```

Comment: I've already written that.....after writing this... I'm getting that blank space.

Comment: Actually in my main activity I'm using the navigation drawer activity.... I'm not sure if due to that it is not getting hidden

Comment: Even I have a navigation drawer in my application & a bottom navigation view in the same activity and I just hide the toolbar using the above code for a specific fragment. I need to see your MainActivity where you are inflating the drawers & loading the fragments.